# Amazon-Working ACM certificate disassociated unexpectedly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-certificate-manager

We have successfully associated multiple domains with a single ACM certificate and configured it with an Elastic Load Balancer.
we are using the EKS service to deploy our application.

So far all the applications are up and running, But suddenly the ACM certificate got automatically, disassociated with the ELB service and returned 400 response errors on all the applications.

We also checked the "cloud trail" events regarding the disassociation of the ACM certificate and we couldn't find any events that happened according to the disassociation of the ACM certificate.

Is there any possibility that the ACM got disassociated.?